# VB Multiple Radio buttons within a group box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, radio-button, groupbox

I have multiple groupboxes on a page each with over 15 radio buttons within them. By problem is that if a single radio button is selected within a groupbox, then none of the other radio buttons in the same groupbox can be selected without un-selecting the selected radio button.

Is there any way that multiple radio buttons within the same groupbox can be selected at the same time? If so, it would be a really great help if I could get a step by step way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: that is why they are called radiobuttons, you can only tune into one station at a time.  Group the mutually exclusive choices into their own group containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how radio buttons are supposed to work. If this is not what you want, then you must use checkboxes instead.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to using VB so pardon my failure.

Comment: Just for reference, checkboxes or radio buttons are not language specific (well, their names may slighly vary, but the expected behavior will be the same).

Comment: As Joel points out, I should have said, this is Windows behaviour as per the Windows Design Guidelines, not language-specific at all. Even if you invented your own language, your radio buttons should work like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how radio buttons are supposed to work, as a radio button is supposed to be a choice between one or the other. Most people will recommend that you use CheckBoxes instead, which allow for multiple boxes to be selected.

You can, however, change the AutoCheck property of all RadioBoxes within the GroupBox to False, then you will need to handle the checked property yourself by using the Click event. For example:

```
Private Sub rdbGridList_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rdbGridList.Click
    If rdbGridList.Checked = False Then
        rdbTreeView.Checked = False
        rdbGridList.Checked = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I needed to use the above instead of CheckBoxes because I have four radio buttons within a "View Options" box, however these were separated into two lots of two radio buttons, and I didn't want to create another group box as it would have looked too messy.

It depends what your program requirements are.